# How to save input from unity inspector to a text file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can we save input from inspector to a text file in unity?

I am trying to move my inputs of a lot coordinates to another project, but i don't find anyway to do it automatically. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you just copy your scene over to the next project?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a prefab of the various gameobjects with data that needs to be saved, then select the newly created prefab, and then export the package with all dependencies.  The package can then be imported into a new project and the components containing the data in the inspector will be available to the new project.

1. Create prefab and rename
2. Drag objects to prefab
3. Select prefab
4. Assets -> Export Package
5. Include all dependencies
6. Import package into new project